# Optimizing service

Tags: android, performance, android-service

I'm working on an app in which I'm required to check when the user switches from one app (eg. Facebook) to another one (eg. Gmail).

For this I'm running a background service and checking the top activity in a loop. As expected, this causes a performance hit and is certainly a bad way of doing this.  I've considered a timer task for this but that would run after every 1 sec, so keeping in view more precision I took the looping way.

As there's no intent broadcasted while this switching happens, I'm forced to take either of the above two methods. Any workaround for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You are using a Background Service, there is no guarantee that your Service will be always running. So,its not appropriate.

2.Periodic Service is also a waste because application switch might happen in less than a second and the cost of awaking a service after every second wouldn't be less.

The option left is you may use a Foreground Service.Foreground Service is in no way cost-efficient but seems to solve your problem. the user will always know that a service is running and can always decide if to enable/disable the service.

**UPDATE :**
If you are really cost-savvy,you may go for Background Service with [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT). It will tell the system to restart and regain the service after the crash and also redeliver the intents that were present at the time of crash happened.

Comment: As I pointed out, I'm using a loop inside the thread (which I started from service), and I've given the user the option to stop the service, from the main activity of the application (from where this service is started). And as you've just answered, switching can take place in less than a second, so I can't really rely on some periodic service or timer tasks. Using foreground service may solve it, but problem is the performance hit and the CPU usage that would be same in background service. So, my question still stands, is there any way to get it cost efficient and still yielding the results.

Comment: My problem is not related to service crash,  it's concerned with the loop that I use which is too much for the CPU to handle (as it's infinite unless user stops the service or something else happens). Regarding the START_REDELIVER_INTENT, I guess this would be useful when Android kills the service or it crashes due to some reason. But that's not the problem,  I just want to reduce CPU load while getting desired results.